# ERROR ON: numApprovals = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public static int AwaitingApprovals()
{
    int numApprovals = 0;
    string sql = "SELECT COUNT(Type) AS OpenforApproval FROM dbo.LeaveRequest 
                  WHERE Type IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13, 14, 16, 22)
                  GROUP BY MgtApproval HAVING (MgtApproval IS NULL";
    //"SELECT COUNT(EffectiveDate) AS OpenforApproval FROM LeaveRequest 
    // GROUP BY TimeStampApproval HAVING (TimeStampApproval IS NULL)";

    using (cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString()))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            numApprovals = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    return numApprovals;
}
```

Comment: what error? please edit the question to describe the error.

Comment: You have not asked a question. Please ask one. Also, if your problem involves an exception, then please post the entire exception. Catch it, and then post ex.ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL syntax is wrong. You have an opening parenthesis after HAVING that doesn't have any closing parenthesis. Add a closing parenthesis or just remove the opening parenthesis.

```
string sql =
   "SELECT COUNT(Type) AS OpenforApproval " +
   "FROM dbo.LeaveRequest " +
   "WHERE Type IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13, 14, 16, 22) " +
   "GROUP BY MgtApproval " +
   "HAVING MgtApproval IS NULL";
```

Comment: Thank you Guffa, you've corrected my syntax and it's working.

Answer (score 5):

It seems your query is incorrect.

At the outset, I cannot understand the need of group by & you are missing a ")" towards the end of the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a bracket, but also, you don't need a GROUP BY and a HAVING, you can just have an additional part of your WHERE clause.

```
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(Type) AS OpenforApproval FROM dbo.LeaveRequest WHERE Type IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13, 14, 16, 22) AND MgtApproval IS NULL";
```

Comment: Hi Robin Day, Thank you to you as well.  Your syntax works on me as well.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a closing parenthesis at the end of your query statement.  Wouldn't *that* cause `cmd.ExecuteScalar` to raise an exception?